# GUI for Spring BEAN xml editor in intellij idea

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I've started learning Spring recently. I'm following a tutorial which is based on SPRING STS, but I'm using Intellij idea.

In STS, there is a bean editor but I couldn't find any in Intellij idea.
Is there any spring bean editor in INTELLIJ IDEA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not exactly, but Intellij will usually automatically detect your Spring bean configuration and put a green bean icon where you are using those beans.  If not, you can go to Project Structure->Facets, click the + sign, and then add the Spring facet yourself.  This works with both XML and Java config.

Note that Intellij doesn't have either a Spring Integration or Spring Batch diagram like STS does, in case you are using either of those.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't one. Instead, you can use the code completion, navigation and error highlighting features for editing the Spring xml file directly.